# Create or update secret

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have the following action:

```
- name: Apply Nginx Configuration
  env:
    SERVICE_NAME: ${{ secrets.SERVICE_NAME }}
  run: |
    gcloud secrets create "${SERVICE_NAME}_nginx_config" --replication-policy='automatic' --data-file=nginx.conf || \
      gcloud secrets versions add "${SERVICE_NAME}_nginx_config" --data-file=nginx.conf

    export PROJECT_NUMBER=$(gcloud projects describe $(gcloud config get-value project) --format='value(projectNumber)')
    gcloud secrets add-iam-policy-binding "${SERVICE_NAME}_nginx_config" --member=serviceAccount:${PROJECT_NUMBER}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --role='roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor'
```

Is there a better way to create, if it doesn't exist, and if it does, update a secret? My action above fails because the first command fails.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with this:

```
- name: Setup Nginx Secret
  env:
    SERVICE_NAME: ${{ secrets.SERVICE_NAME }}
  run: |
    if ! gcloud secrets create "${SERVICE_NAME}_nginx_config" --replication-policy='automatic' --data-file=nginx.conf; then
      echo "Secret already exists. Adding new version..."
      gcloud secrets versions add "${SERVICE_NAME}_nginx_config" --data-file=nginx.conf
    fi

    export PROJECT_NUMBER=$(gcloud projects describe $(gcloud config get-value project) --format='value(projectNumber)')
    gcloud secrets add-iam-policy-binding "${SERVICE_NAME}_nginx_config" --member=serviceAccount:${PROJECT_NUMBER}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --role='roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor'
```

Comment: Think about security and where to store your secret before adding it in your secret manager. And you will see that my answer make more sense than at the first look.

Comment: Of course, but those secrets are just a nginx configuration.

Comment: So, if it's not secret, with don't you simply use env vars? Or files on Cloud Storage? It will be cheaper!

Comment: This "secret" will be used in a Cloud Run pod (Run runs on top of Kubernetes). Since I want to use the official Nginx image without modifying it, one way to inject the configuration is to mount the directory in the container, so I do this via secrets.

Comment: Oh, smart, you mount your config as a volume, and not as an env vars!!

Comment: Are you being sarcastic? If not, please tell me how I can change the default configuration of Nginx file using environment variables.

Comment: No no, I'm sincere! It's really smart!! It's a great idea to load a config file in a volume thanks to Secret Manager! I remember I wrote an article about that: https://medium.com/google-cloud/mount-a-file-as-a-volume-in-cloud-run-facc74c02cc6 And being not english-native, be sarcastic in english is out of my skills!

Comment: Fair enough, thank you!